# Android Studio crash - Mac High Sierra

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, macos-high-sierra

I have an issue using Android Studio (and other Java applications) on my Macbook. This appears to happen randomly when using Android Studio, and it's impossible to use my Macbook to code in Android....
The issue is as follows:

```
#  Internal Error (loopnode.hpp:747), pid=21989, tid=0x0000000000005803
#  guarantee(d->_idx < _idom_size) failed:

Current thread (0x00007f908c82a000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=22531, stack(0x0000700011823000,0x0000700011923000)]

Stack: [0x0000700011823000,0x0000700011923000],  sp=0x000070001191b820,  free space=994k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x57e1be]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x3f8
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x1e2707]  report_vm_error(char const*, int, char const*, char const*)+0x54
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a701d]  PhaseIdealLoop::dom_depth(Node*) const+0x61
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3b3d46]  PhaseIdealLoop::get_early_ctrl(Node*)+0x86
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3b40e1]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_early(VectorSet&, Node_List&, Node_Stack&)+0x229
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3b65c5]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_and_optimize(bool, bool)+0x579
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x1ab6f9]  Compile::Optimize()+0x3a5
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x1aea4b]  Compile::Compile(ciEnv*, C2Compiler*, ciMethod*, int, bool, bool, bool)+0x8e1
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x14f20a]  C2Compiler::compile_method(ciEnv*, ciMethod*, int)+0xb2
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x1b19fe]  CompileBroker::invoke_compiler_on_method(CompileTask*)+0x5b2
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x1b3f45]  CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()+0x291
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x53912d]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0x9b
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x53a7e4]  JavaThread::run()+0x1c0
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x45bf0a]  java_start(Thread*)+0xf6
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x36c1]  _pthread_body+0x154
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x356d]  _pthread_body+0x0
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x2c5d]  thread_start+0xd
C  0x0000000000000000
```

https://pastebin.com/KiqZ1h65

Can anyone help me solving this?

Comment: Seems to be a memory related issue. Do you have any disk space left?

Comment: I still have about 11 Gb free on disk. Why do you think it's a memory issue?

Comment: `free space=994k` seems a bit low, just guessing

Comment: gonna try to tweak memory parameters and see if it helps, thanks ;) but the main thing is that this error happens almost every single time:                      #  Internal Error (loopnode.hpp:747), pid=21989, tid=0x0000000000005803
#  guarantee(d->_idx < _idom_size) failed: - and I still haven't figured out what that means...

Comment: another thing I found out is that when the crash occurs, the free space is always 994k, odd...

Comment: It's probably looping somewhere and trying to allocate another 1024k, so it doesn't actually crash until it is below that.